# mysql like query, how can you sort targeting two columns in a table but sorting by the results matched by one column

Tags: php, mysql

Using the code below, i am able to return all products that match the search word. However they order in a way that a product with a name different from the search phrase appears first and one with a matching name later because the description had a match.

How can i sort and return the products whose name matches the search phrase first?

```
    $sqli = "
SELECT * 
  FROM product 
 WHERE";

Foreach($strarray as $key=>$value){
If($key > 0){
$sqli = $sqli . "OR";
}
$sqli = $sqli . " (Name LIKE '%" . $value . "%' or Description LIKE '%" . $value . "%')";
}
```

Comment: `ORDER BY name LIKE '%value%' DESC`

Answer (score 2):

Add an `ORDER BY` clause:

```
$ssql .= " ORDER BY Name LIKE '%" . $value . "%' DESC"
```

A boolean expression is 1 for TRUE and 0 for FALSE, so sorting by a condition orders by whether the row matches the condition.

BTW, you should learn to use prepared statements to prevent SQL injection. See [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: This worked perfect. Thank You. Thank you for your concern on php injection too. I will learn it immediately.